# Eyewitness weather reports in India?

Tags: online-resources, india, weather-and-climate

We are trying to decide whether the weather is currently suitable for Goa and Kerala as a beach destination - weather forecast sites show showers as their forecast, however this is not very informative (they show forecast several hours of showers but in actuality it could be that small short showers are occurring in parts of the decried area so the weather is instead good 90% of the time). Are there web sites where real descriptions of the weather are posted regularly by locals or tourists in the area?

(E.g. surf forecasting sites like magicseaweed have eyewitness descriptions of the surf as well as forecasts, I'm looking for an Indian weather equivalent).

Answer (score 1):

[Pressurenet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ca.cumulonimbus.barometernetwork&hl=en) might be what you're after.  It's still growing, but it allows people to report live stats via their phone of the weather where they are.  I'm in Sydney at present and there's usually a few around me being reported at any given moment - although it's definitely not huge at time of writing.

Not sure of its coverage for India, but may be worth a try. Let us know.